# iOS - How to display UIView while an activity view is still animating?

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

I have code to display a "Loading..." view with an activity wheel when my app is loading certain screens.  If the loading takes an especially long time (say, more than 4 seconds) then I'd like to display an additional message that says something like "Sorry this is taking so long, please be patient!"  The way I'm doing this is by using an NSTimer on a 4 second delay that calls a method to create a wait view and then overlays this new view on the loading view in such a way that the words doesn't overlap.  If the page loads in less than 4 seconds, then the loading view is hidden, the wait view never gets triggered and the user goes on his or her merry way.

When I test screen loads that take more than 4 seconds, I can't seem to get the additional view to display.  Here's my code:

```
// this method is triggered elsewhere in my code
// right before the code to start loading a screen
- (void)showActivityViewer
{     
    tooLong = YES;
    waitTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0
                                                   target:self
                                                 selector:@selector(createWaitAlert)
                                                 userInfo:nil
                                                  repeats:NO];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer: waitTimer forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    loadingView = [LoadingView createLoadingView:self.view.bounds.size.width     :self.view.bounds.size.height];    
    [self.view addSubview: loadingView];

    // this next line animates the activity wheel which is a subview of loadingView
    [[[loadingView subviews] objectAtIndex:0] startAnimating]; 
}

- (void)createWaitAlert
{
    [waitTimer invalidate];
    if (tooLong) 
    {
        UIView *waitView = [LoadingView createWaitView:self.view.bounds.size.width :self.view.bounds.size.height];
        [self.view addSubview:waitView];
    }
}

// this method gets triggered elsewhere in my code
// when the screen has finished loading and is ready to display
- (void)hideActivityViewer
{
    tooLong = NO;
    [[[loadingView subviews] objectAtIndex:0] stopAnimating];
    [loadingView removeFromSuperview];
    loadingView = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are executing this from the main thread? Try this:

```
- (void)showActivityViewer
{     
    tooLong = YES;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create(@"myQueue", NULL), ^{
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:4];
        [self createWaitAlert];
    });

    loadingView = [LoadingView createLoadingView:self.view.bounds.size.width     :self.view.bounds.size.height];    
    [self.view addSubview: loadingView];

    // this next line animates the activity wheel which is a subview of loadingView
    [[[loadingView subviews] objectAtIndex:0] startAnimating]; 
}

- (void)createWaitAlert
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (tooLong) 
        {
            UIView *waitView = [LoadingView createWaitView:self.view.bounds.size.width :self.view.bounds.size.height];
            [self.view addSubview:waitView];
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is that supposed to do?  I tried it, but no change in my results.  By the way, I added a log print statement at the very beginning of createWaitAlert, and it is isn't even printing until after the loading view disappears.  Does that mean it's not on the main thread?

Comment: This is supposed to make sure your add code is done in the main thread. I think the problem is because you added your timer to the same run loop as the one that does the heavy lifting work preparing your UI, it doesn't fire. The timer is not a sync'ed mechanism, basically the runloop checks it every so often to see if the fire time has passed and then fire. If the loop is busy doing something else, it never checks.

Comment: Ah ok.  So how would I go about putting the timer on another thread so that it executes simultaneously with the "heavy lifting" that is being done on the main thread?

Comment: I would not use the NSTimer all together, but that's my personal preference. I don't have Xcode with me now but I tried to update my response above with what I think the code should be. Basically you wait in your own thread so you don't block on anything else, and when it's time, call the main thread to setup the extra view.